# Use both JSP and React js

Tags: reactjs, jsp

Is it possible after I send a request to my server from React to not send back the response to React, but open a page from server and let my server retrieve all the process?

The thing is that I want to play a popup with a course and all the info are being sent to the server and there is already an implementation with jQuery and JavaScript.

So can I play a popup independently of React? Thank you!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about. Do you want a popup window? Use `window.open`.